# Spring start another application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

Spring launch of other services.

I have a main application (**HUB**)
Service for processing requests (**connector**)
A service that stores data in the **H2 database**
When starting the hub, all services and the H2 database must be started!

**How to do it correctly?**

At the moment, I start all the services by simulating the console commands `java -jar service_name.jar` via Proccess
But I think this is a very bad approach. I can't monitor the processes of the services in any way.
For example, if I start another service "connector" from the command line, the hub will be able to see it through eureka, but if it wants to kill it, it will not be able. Because the hub does not know anything about the process instance.
I see a problem here.
Moreover, together with the hub, I want to run h2database, then I need to monitor the memory that the base occupies. What is the best way to do this?

Maybe I didn't express myself well.
I will hope for your support.

I am using *eureka* in this project. Maybe there are ways to run services using it?

Comment: This sounds like something Docker would be good at?

Comment: @jared unfortunately this is not possible in this case

Comment: The idea is that the hub has a certain number of services that themselves rise when necessary and go out when not needed. I'm bad at this topic, so I'll be happy to give you some advice. But from the fact that I wrap the services in docker in this case, nothing will change. I need him to run them and monitor them whenever possible.